# How to play MIDI input in Linux

Tags: linux, audio, serial-port, arduino, midi

I am sending serial data to my raspberry pi from my arduino then converting the serial data to MIDI using this program: [link](http://www.spikenzielabs.com/SpikenzieLabs/Serial_MIDI.html). Is there any program out there that will take the midi input from the converter program and send it out the pi's audio jack in real time?

Comment: I don't know about Pi (or embedded linux in general), but alsa has a built-in midi player. aplaymidi or something.

Comment: @jpaugh: But those still require a MIDI sequencer or synthesizer on the end of a MIDI cable.

Comment: ?? Any MIDI program uses *ALSA* at the lowest level on Linux. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @jpaugh: Sure, but ALSA supports multiple output mechanisms. One is MIDI UART, which is useless here. Another is PCM, which requires software to perform the sequencing and synthesizing in order to turn the MIDI events into PCM audio.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [fluidsynth](http://fluidsynth.elementsofsound.org/) as a softsynth. I haven't run any on the pi, though. There's also a lot of others like amsynth, hexter, xsynth-dssi etc and some of them might be more suitable than others.

You might try running `apt-cache search` with some suitable keywords and look for programs available on the pi.

Answer (score 1):

[TiMidity++](http://timidity.sourceforge.net/) is a software MIDI sequencer and synthesizer that supports multiple audio and patch formats.

Comment: Probably hard to put on a Pi, though. But, who knows?

Comment: @jpaugh: http://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora-secondary/releases/18/Everything/arm/os/Packages/t/timidity++-2.14.0-2.fc18.armv5tel.rpm

Comment: Not every arm is as limited as a Pi, though. Still, this is linux, so anything's possible!

Comment: @jpaugh: My PogoPlug can do it. RPi isn't even a challenge.

Comment: +1 In that case, you are infinitely more qualified here than I.

Comment: I  downvoted this answer, for the capability dsolanim askes for is not listed  with tiMidity++. If the real time aspect is accomodated, this should be confirmed in the answer, not just that program is great and it can do everything.